# Rails - calling a method in controller using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to call a method in controller from my index.html file while staying on the same path... is it possible... can anyone help me

index.html

```
<%= link_to "Click", controller: "products", action: "click" %>
```

controller.rb

```
def click
    puts "click called!!!"
end
```

routes

```
get 'click'
```

Error: Missing :controller key on routes definition

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation of [Rails Routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), you got to specify the controller and the action where it is routed, in your case the `Products` controller within the `click` action.

So in your routes.rb file your proper get syntax should include the destination, like this:

`get '/products/:id', to: 'products#click'`

Also in your `link_to` you should include the ID of the product so the routing passes the id to the controller and you should include logic in your controller to manipulate that ID how you need. [See this](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/05/rails-link_to-method/).

PS: Don't name your action `click` , name it as the actual action to perform on a product, like `show`. Please also check what [Resources routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) is.